# Email is not sending through sendgrid and also not showing any error/ node.js

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

auth.js
Whenever I try to register new account it's shows me an error 'message" unauthorized', i am not getting what exactly happen.

[image]

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email } = req.body;

        // Make sure this account doesn't already exist
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (user) return res.status(401).json({message: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.'});

        const newUser = new User({ ...req.body, role: "basic" });

        const user_ = await newUser.save();

        await sendVerificationEmail(user_, req, res);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false, message: error.message})
    }
};
```

sending email for verification

```
async function sendVerificationEmail(user, req, res){
    try{
        const token = user.generateVerificationToken();

        // Save the verification token
        await token.save();

        let subject = "Account Verification Token";
        let to = user.email;
        let from = process.env.FROM_EMAIL;
        let link="http://"+req.headers.host+"/api/auth/verify/"+token.token;
        let html = `<p>Hi ${user.username}<p><br><p>Please click on the following <a href="${link}">link</a> to verify your account.</p> 
                  <br><p>If you did not request this, please ignore this email.</p>`;

        await sendEmail({to, from, subject, html});

        res.status(200).json({message: 'A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.'});
    }catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    }
}
```

Please if you find any solution reply as soon as possible
TIA

Comment: Looking at the response, looks like error is in "sendVerificationEmail" function. It's possible that SendGrid is sending the Unauthorized error.

Comment: show your server intialization code\

Comment: there is two possibilities, one you forgot to load the env file or the secret key is wrong

Comment: Put the api key in .env and used require(‘dotenv’).config() on the top of the same file

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar you mean server.js?

Answer (score 0):

I changed to nodemailer + sendgrid now it's working and use gmail service

Comment: Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here. I'm glad you got this working. I just wanted to note that when you say you weren't getting an error, that wasn't quite correct. You were catching the error correctly and then returning a 500 status in your code with the message "Unauthorized". So there was an error and it was something to do with your API credentials. So you were handling the error correctly, you just needed to fix the authorisation issue.